# finding the shortest way to my from one airport to another

Tags: database

I want to create an in-memory definition for a set of airline routes for a small airline company.  I want to maintain a list of all of my planes and their current locations (or their destination location if they are currently in the air).  One of the possible locations needs to be “hangar” for maintenance or repairs.  I want to have the full airline schedule available so that I can look for available flights.  I also want to store information on which planes are operating each schedule.  Design a set of in-memory data structures to store this information without the use of a back end database.  I’m not interested in seeing how this information would be persisted to disk.

Next, assuming that a customer comes to the ticketing counter at one of my airports when it opens at 6:00am, I want to be able to give a customer the fastest option to get from one airport to another.  Keep in mind that it may take more than one flight to get from one airport to another.  Describe how you would fulfill this request with your data structures

Comment: Funny how this started off almost sounding like a real question, then ended up just using the wording from the school assignment from which it sprang.

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.

Comment: tagged with database - yet the homework says no database...

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to look into the traveling salesman problem.  That's very similar to what you are being asked to do.